# Convert WEBP images to PNG by Linux command

Tags: linux, image, command, webp

I have many `webp format images in a folder but with .jpg` extension like

```
abc-test.jpg
```

It's a `webp` format image. I want it to convert in `.png` format with same name for that I have used this command and it worked

```
find . -name "*.jpg" -exec dwebp {} -o {}.png \;
```

It converted all `webp` images to `.png` but the issue is it's saving images like this:

```
abc-test.jpg.png
```

But my requirement is to save it without `.jpg` extension like

```
abc-test.png
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

If you have many to convert/rename, I would recommend you use **GNU Parallel** and not only get them converted faster by doing them I parallel, but also take advantage of the ability to modify filenames.

The command you want is:

```
parallel dwebp {} -o {.}.png ::: *.jpg
```

where the `{.}` means *"the filename without the original extension"*.

If you want to recurse into subdirectories too, you can use:

```
find . -name "*.jpg" -print0 | parallel -0 dwebp {} -o {.}.png
```

If you want a progress meter, or an *"estimated time of arrival"*, you can add `--progress` or `--eta` after the `parallel` command.

If you want to see what **GNU Parallel** would run, without actually running anything, add `--dry-run`.

I commend **GNU Parallel**  to you in this age where CPUs are getting *"fatter"* (more cores) rather than faster.

Comment: Very interesting, thanks. For anyone unfamiliar with webp (like I was), you might first need to install the following packages: `sudo aptitude install parallel webp`. And for webp files with the correct extension, simply do `parallel dwebp {} -o {.}.png ::: *.webp`.

Comment: More info: [GNU Parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) ,
                 - 
                 -          
Memo: [https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_cheat.pdf](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_cheat.pdf)

Answer (score 52):

### How to convert .webp images to .png on Linux

*Tested on Linux Ubuntu 20.04*

This question is the top hit for the [Google search of "linux convert .webp image to png"](https://www.google.com/search?q=linux%20convert%20.webp%20image%20to%20png&oq=linux%20convert%20.webp%20image%20to%20png&aqs=chrome..69i57.219j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). Therefore, for anyone stumbling here and just wanting that simple answer, here it is:

```bash
# 1. Install the `webp` tool
sudo apt update
sudo apt install webp

# 2. Use it: convert in.webp to out.png
dwebp in.webp -o out.png
```

Done! You now have `out.png`.

#### References

1. I learned about `dwebp` from [the question itself](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55161334/4561887).

Answer (score 7):

I did it with short oneliner that does not require `parallel` to be installed in the system

```
for x in `ls -1 *.jpg`; do dwebp {} -o ${x%.*}.png ::: $x; done
```

And this works for current directory

I would try to amend the @mark-setchell recursive solution so it would look like this:

```
for x in `find . -name "*.jpg"`; do dwebp {} -o ${x%.*}.png ::: $x; done
```

The `${x%.*}` part is the one requiring a word of explanation here - it tells bash to take `.` and everything after the dot from the `x` variable.
It is prone to misbehave for names with more dots as I did not check if regex here is lazy or greedy - the answer can be tuned further therefore.

Comment: It is far preferable to use `for x in *.jpg` rather than parsing the output of `ls` - see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: Your commands both have superfluous `:::` in the middle of them - probably left-overs from **GNU Parallel**

Comment: @MarkSetchell thanks, TIL - will check that and fix the answer if all works well so this is as clean as possible :)

Answer (score -1):

If the problem is with linux image viewers - thats the reason of convertion - then I found that: [here](https://itsfoss.com/webp-ubuntu-linux/)

"Add WebP support to GNOME Image Viewer in Ubuntu and Other Linux
By default, the photo viewer does not support WebP images files. However, you can add WebP support by installing webp-pixbuf-loader library. Not only it allows you to open WebP files in GNOME Image Viewer, it also displays thumbnails for WebP files in the file explorer.

On Ubuntu-based Linux distributions, you can install this library using a PPA. Use the following commands one by one:"

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:krifa75/eog-ordissimo
sudo apt update
sudo apt install webp-pixbuf-loader
```

Answer (score -4):

A good thing to do is to use sed along with mv. It matches the pattern and replaces with a newer one.

```
for file in *.jpg;
do
   mv "$file" "`echo $file | sed s/.jpg/.png/`"
done
```

if you want to retain the old files instead of **mv** you can use **cp**

Comment: completely no use. these are different formats, changing extension is insufficient.